# Array not sorting properly when interpreting strings as numbers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Ive been trying to adapt this code found in another thread so that instead of comparing the value in the first coloumn it uses the last one which is a number stored as a string . I have changed the coloumn number but it still sorts by the first.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String[][] data = new String[][] {
                new String[] { "Adam","3", "12" },
                new String[] { "Sam","5", "22" },
                new String[] { "Joe","2", "3" },
                new String[] { "Ryan","4", "4" },
                new String[] { "Leroy","2", "5" },
                new String[] { "Smith","1", "6" },};

        Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(final String[] entry1, final String[] entry2) {
                final String St1 = entry1[2];
                final String St2 = entry2[2];
                return St2.compareTo(St1);

            }
        });

        for (final String[] s : data) {
            System.out.println(s[0] + " " + s[1]+ " " + s[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sorting by the last coloumn , always sorting by the first

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: Rows to be order by the highest to lowest number in the third coloumn like Sam 5 22
Adam 3 12
Smith 1 6
Leroy 2 5
Ryan 4 4
Joe 2 3

Comment: if you want to sort by number, why are you comparing strings without conversion them to numbers?

Comment: Erm thats what i dont understand/know how to do ?

Comment: so, your question how to convert string to number in java?

Comment: Any reason you're using a String[] and not a POJO?

Comment: @Duda777 Your edit produced invalid Java code. If you want to edit it, then do it properly, please.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to sort the strings *numerically*, you must convert the strings to numbers first, otherwise the numbers will be sorted *alphabetically*, ie "2" wil be grater than "10" (because 2 comes after 1 in ascii):

```
public int compare(final String[] entry1, final String[] entry2) {
    String st1 = entry1[2];
    String st2 = entry2[2];
    int n1 = Integer.parseInt(st1);
    int n2 = Integer.parseInt(st2);
    return Integer.compare(n2, n1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that , i thought it was something simple like that

Comment: shouldn't the final return statement be `Integer.compare(n1, n2)`?

Comment: @brett this mimics OP code and comment above supports too "want to sort highest to lowest". However, if sorting is wanted in natural order (lowest to highest), then yes.